# How to set location in Starcraft 64?

Tags: controllers, starcraft, starcraft-64

When press right, screen jumps to my base and tool tip says "Map location R selected". When I press other directions it says the same, just with letter for the direction I pressed. How do I set the locations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Holding L while selecting a d-pad direction will set a camera hotkey. All four available hotkeys default to your main base.